# Value of $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}$?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Not so thrilling... An exercise of one of my daughters.

How to evaluate

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}?$$ I made several substitution namely:

- Factorisation of $x^2+x+1$
- Then use of $\sinh t$
- Then substitution by $e^u$
- To get a rational fraction with at the denominator a degree two polynomial with two real roots that can be integrated with partial fraction decomposition.

Is there something more straight forward?

Comment: use the function $$arctanh$$

Comment: $x^2+x+1$ can't be factorised using real numbers - only complex numbers, which in turn makes the integral harder. Please update your question to show all your working - not just the descriptions.

Comment: Would $$x^2+x+1=\left(x+\frac12\right)^2+\frac34$$ help?

Comment: @J.M. That's what I mean in the first step I mentioned. I realize that my wording is probably incorrect as this is not a proper factorization.I don't know what is the proper English wording that describes the transformation  $a x^2 +b x +c$ into $ a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2+c -\left(\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2$

Comment: Yes, it's often called "completing the square" in English. From there, you can use either the tangent or the hyperbolic sine as seen fit.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks... I now have to remember the wording "completing the square"!

Comment: Perhaps not worth a full answer, but substituting $y=1/x$ leaves you with $\int_0^1 \frac{dy}{\sqrt{y^2+y+1}}$, which is arguably a little neater. You still need to play around with completing the square / your substitution of choice, but I'd argue it's at least marginally friendlier in that form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With
>   $\ds{t \equiv \root{x^{2} + x + 1} - x \implies
> x = -\,{t^{2} - 1 \over 2t - 1}}$:

\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x\root{x^{2} + x + 1}} & =
-2\int_{\root{3} - 1}^{1/2}\,\,\,{\dd t \over 1 - t^{2}} =
\int_{\root{3} - 1}^{1/2}\pars{-\,{1 \over 1 - t} - {1 \over 1 + t}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\left.\ln\pars{1 - t \over 1 + t}\right\vert_{\ \root{3}\ -\ 1}^{\ 1/2} =
\ln\pars{{1 - 1/2 \over 1 + 1/2}\,
{\bracks{\root{3} - 1} + 1 \over 1 - \bracks{\root{3} - 1}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\ds{\ln\pars{1 + {2 \over 3}\,\root{3}}}} \approx 0.7677
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

We have:
$$ \int\frac{dx}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^2+3x+3}}=C+\log(x+1)-\log\left(3+x+2\sqrt{x^2+3x+3}\right)\tag{1}$$
hence:
$$ \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+x+1}} = \color{blue}{\log\left(1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}.\tag{2}$$
To check this, it is enough to notice that
$$ I=\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}=2\int_{3}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(x-1)\sqrt{x^2+3}}\tag{3}$$
and by setting $x=\sqrt{3}\sinh z$ in the last integral,
$$ I = 2\int_{\text{arcsinh}\sqrt{3}}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{3}\sinh z-1}\tag{4} $$
that is converted into the integral of a simple rational function by the substitution $z=\log u$.

Comment: I don't see what is getting easier here. How do you perform the integration? I mean, the original function has a primitive $\log x-\log(2+x+2\sqrt{1+x+x^2})$, but if we just write that, then we do not show how it was obtained...

Comment: @amWhy: is it better now?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio This is almost what I did, but then you have the simple rational fraction that is not so simple... I know simple is a relative question!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio On my side I get for the denominator $\sqrt {3} u^2 -\sqrt{3}-u$???

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: all right, but it makes little difference. Factor that second-degree polynomial in order to have a partial fraction decomposition of the integrand function, leading to some logarithmic contributes.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+x+1}} & \stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}}{=}\int_0^1 \frac{d x}{\sqrt{1+x+x^2}} \\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{d x}{\sqrt{\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Letting $x+\frac{1}{2} =\frac {\sqrt 3}{ 2 }\sinh \theta$ transforms the integral into
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+x+1}} &=\int_{\sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}^{\sinh ^{-1}(\sqrt{3})} \frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \cosh \theta}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \cosh \theta} d \theta \\
&=\sinh ^{-1}(\sqrt{3})-\sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) \\
& \approx 0.76765
\end{aligned}
$$